# What is the Global Registrar?

Tags: addresses, name-registrar, registrars

Some guy on reddit [found an address with 235 ETH](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/47mdl7/apparently_this_is_my_address_do_i_really_have/) in his wallet. He was confused about how he managed to get so much ETH. Commentators told him that it is the *global registrar object*.

Here is an interesting snippet of his [command line output](http://pastebin.com/LY2dQ1RP):

```
namereg: {
    address: "0xc6d9d2cd449a754c494264e1809c50e34d64562b",
    AuctionEnded: function(),
    Changed: function(),
    NewBid: function(),
    PrimaryChanged: function(),
    Registrar: function(),
    addr: function(),
    allEvents: function(),
    content: function(),
    disown: function(),
    name: function(),
    owner: function(),
    reserve: function(),
    setAddress: function(),
    setContent: function(),
    setSubRegistrar: function(),
    subRegistrar: function(),
    transfer: function()
}
```

What is `namereg`? What is the *global registrar*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Global Registrar seems to already be hard coded into geth.

```
beefee@Kumquat:~$ geth console
I0330 00:29:31.337735    8794 database.go:71] Alloted 16MB cache to /home/beefee/.ethereum/chaindata
...
at block: 1235423 (Tue, 29 Mar 2016 10:10:53 AEDT)
modules: admin:1.0 db:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 shh:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0
> registrar
{
  address: "0x33990122638b9132ca29c723bdf037f1a891a70c",
  Changed: function(),
  PrimaryChanged: function(),
  Registrar: function(),
  addr: function(),
  allEvents: function(),
  content: function(),
  disown: function(),
  name: function(),
  owner: function(),
  register: function(),
  reserve: function(),
  setAddress: function(),
  setContent: function(),
  setSubRegistrar: function(),
  subRegistrar: function(),
  transfer: function()
}
> registrar.addr("BeefPool.net")
"0xbeef281b81d38096cd8b1d8f69f77be100000000"
> registrar.owner("BeefPool.net")
"0xbeef281b81d383336aca8b2b067a526227638087"
```

The answer 5chdn seems to give an invalid Global Registrar.

```
// Using the default hard-coded registrar
> registrar.addr("ethpool")
"0x4bb96091ee9d802ed039c4d1a5f6216f90f81b01"
// Invalid Global Registrar from 5chdn
> registrar = GlobalRegistrar.at('0xc6d9d2cd449a754c494264e1809c50e34d64562b');
{
  address: "0xc6d9d2cd449a754c494264e1809c50e34d64562b",
  Changed: function(),
  PrimaryChanged: function(),
  Registrar: function(),
  addr: function(),
  allEvents: function(),
  content: function(),
  disown: function(),
  name: function(),
  owner: function(),
  register: function(),
  reserve: function(),
  setAddress: function(),
  setContent: function(),
  setSubRegistrar: function(),
  subRegistrar: function(),
  transfer: function()
}
> registrar.addr("ethpool")
"0x"
```

Also, from https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/common/registrar/registrar.go#L56-L63 :

```
  GlobalRegistrarAddr = "0x33990122638b9132ca29c723bdf037f1a891a70c" // frontier
  HashRegAddr         = "0x23bf622b5a65f6060d855fca401133ded3520620" // frontier
  UrlHintAddr         = "0x73ed5ef6c010727dfd2671dbb70faac19ec18626" // frontier
```

Here they are:

https://live.ether.camp/account/33990122638b9132ca29c723bdf037f1a891a70c
https://live.ether.camp/account/23bf622b5a65f6060d855fca401133ded3520620
https://live.ether.camp/account/73ed5ef6c010727dfd2671dbb70faac19ec18626

Comment: In `geth-1.4.6` I get a ReferenceError for both `namereg` as well as `registrar`. Did this change with the last couple of geth versions or what?

Answer (score 5):

A namereg contract allows associating human-comprehensible names with human-incomprehensible data. One of the use cases is creating a global address book for Ethereum addresses. Using a namereg contract, one may send ether to "5chdn" instead of "0x<some hex value>". One may also register things like IPFS hashes, allowing one to use it as a decentralized DNS for a decentralized Web.

The global registrar is a commonly shared namereg contract that (as I understand it) will be integrated with user-friendly clients like Mist by default.

Answer (score 1):

Update: *Note, this is the testnet registrar!*

Cool, in addition to the other answer, it's already implemented. [To test that](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3iau5v/name_registrar_is_awesome/), type in your geth console:

```
registrar = GlobalRegistrar.at('0xc6d9d2cd449a754c494264e1809c50e34d64562b');
```

To set up your own name and give it a test:

```
registrar.reserve.sendTransaction('5chdn', {from: eth.accounts[0]});
registrar.setAddress.sendTransaction('5chdn', eth.accounts[0], true, {from: eth.accounts[0]});
```

To test, see if you can resolve "5chdn" to your ethereum address:

```
registrar.addr('5chdn');
```

Now, whenever anyone want to send you some ether, you only need to do this:

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: registrar.addr('5chdn'), value: web3.toWei(1, 'ether'), gas: 21000});
```

You'll need to run the `GlobalRegistrar.at()` line every time you start geth until this gets hard coded.

You can also replace the second parameter of `.setAddress()` above with a contract's address to "call it by name".

Comment: registrar.addr('5chdn'); returns "0x" for me, is that correct ?

Comment: It seems this is the testnet registrar, _oops_ :-)