# Registrar in a private testnet

Tags: testnets, network, name-registrar

I've created a test network `--networkid="11111"` and I was able to create the "greeter" contract as an excercise.

Now, I'm following [this guide](https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/contract_namereg.html) and I am trying to register a name, but with no luck: `registrar.addr("myname")` returns `0x`.

Is it possible to register a name within the test network or am I doing something wrong?

A similar unanswered question [is at the forums](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/2304/how-do-i-get-the-registrar-to-work-on-a-private-testchain).

Answer (score 2):

Here's some info on the Registrar in Mainnet and Testnet - [What is the Global Registrar?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/what-is-the-global-registrar).

You will have to compile and deploy the registrar code to your private test network. You will find the Solidity source code at [ethereum/dapp-bin](https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/tree/master/registrar)
.

You will need to keep track of the addresses you have deployed the registrar contracts to so you can use them in subsequent sessions.