# How to automaticlly find the contract?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, ether, console

I created a private network using go-ethereum with 2 clien which are VMs(ubuntu 14.04).

On VM1, I created a contract:

```
N1greeterSource ='contract mortal { address owner; function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner); } } contract greeter is mortal { string greeting; function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; } function changeMessage(string myMsg) returns (string){ greeting = myMsg; return myMsg; } function greet() returns (string) { return greeting; } }'
N1greeterCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(N1greeterSource);
_greeting = "Hello world !";
N1greeterContract = web3.eth.contract(N1greeterCompiled.greeter.info.abiDefinition);
N1greeter = N1greeterContract.new(_greeting,{from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: N1greeterCompiled.greeter.code, gas: 310000}, function(e, contract){
    if(!e) {

      if(!contract.address) {
        console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");

      } else {
        console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
        console.log(contract);
      }

    }
    else{
    console.log("Error:>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    console.log(e);
    }

})
```

On VM2, I see contract by:

```
N1greeter = eth.contract([{ constant: false, inputs: [], name: "kill", outputs: [], type: "function" }, { constant: false, inputs: [{ name: "myMsg", type: "string" }], name: "changeMessage", outputs: [{ name: "", type: "string" }], type: "function" }, { constant: false, inputs: [], name: "greet", outputs: [{ name: "", type: "string" }], type: "function" }, { inputs: [{ name: "_greeting", type: "string" }], type: "constructor" }] ).at("0x526e636021fbfef1584097690798145ff32be21a");
```

Everything is OK.

But, I don't know how to VM2 can automaticlly find the contract? (find address and abi in VM1 to add this code: ***N1greeter = eth.contract(abi).at(address)***)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the **name registrar** contract that is used to associate your contract's address with a name. In case of a **private testnet**, you will need to deploy the registrar code on your network. In order to do that, you will first have to compile the code from their git [repo](https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/tree/master/registrar), and deploy them on your network just as you would do for any other contract.

For more information on Registrar:[What is the Global Registrar?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/what-is-the-global-registrar)

Another approach to interacting with a contract is using the NatSpec Protocol. For further information on that, here is the link: [NatSpec Github wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Contracts-and-Transactions#natspec).

Comment: Please show me how to deploy registrar. I'm working on go-ethereum console. And it's too difficult to find "registrar"

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the answer to your query

Comment: I tried remove lines and break content of "GlobalRegistrar.sol". Then i continue to compile by "web3.eth.compile.solidity" but it has  some strange erros. Please show me how can load "GlobalRegistrar.sol" from console. Thanks